# PostgreSQL 9.6: Why is this pg_restore command working for me but not my colleague?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

We've got a brand new coder on board. As one does, we'd like for him to have a local version of our PostgreSQL database to mess about with.

Dumping the production database as follows worked without issue:

`pg_dump -U username -W -F c dbname > backups/2020_04_24_18_49.db`

Restoring to a test DB I created on my local (running Ubuntu 18.04) as follows worked without issue:

`pg_restore -d dbname 2020_04_24_18_49.db`

Running the same command on my colleague's local (running macOS, not sure of the version) does **not** work without issue. Many, many errors ensue. The first is this one:

`COPY failed for table "TableName": ERROR: new row for relation "TableName" violates check constraint "whitespaceRules_TableName_columnName"`

I have made sure we're running the same version of PostgreSQL. I have ensured the correct roles exist. I have tried dumping different formats. I have tried many things. None has worked.

Please help?

(It should be noted that this is not the only colleague running macOS, so it shouldn't be that. I think)

**Edit:** As requested in a comment, here is the definition of the check constraint:

```
CHECK (("emailAddress" = regexp_replace("emailAddress", '\s+'::text, ''::text, 'g'::text)))
```

Comment: I'd carefully consider whether you should be working on a copy of the production database. Does it contain any PII? What does your privacy and data protection policy look like?

Comment: Was the database empty before you started restoring into it?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Thank you; these are certainly worthwhile points, but let us assume that we have dealt with them and that they lie beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes. Brand new, in fact.

Comment: Can you post the definition of that `whitespaceRules_TableName_columnName` constraint, please? Maybe it uses functions whose behaviour depends on the configuration of the database cluster - make sure to replicate those as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Bergi. I've added the definition to the question. I'm not sure why this would cause issues on his system vs, say, mine, because there are no configuration differences that I can find. But I'm not an expert, and this is definitely getting me thinking, thank you!

Comment: My guess would be something to do with character encoding or language settings. Which might be different because of your different OS. Could you locate a row in your data that causes the trouble?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/220933/188406) could help to figure out if any settings differ.

Comment: These are fantastic and useful suggestions, thank you @Bergi! I'll look into them!

Comment: Could you show the result of `SHOW lc_ctype;` on both databases?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Alas, I can no longer do that - we've got it working! But I suspect you and Bergi were on the money. When i have a moment I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so using `pg_dump` with the `--create` flag did the trick. I'm guessing whatever configuration / encoding / etc mismatches @Borgi and @Laurenz Albe were pointing at in their comments were handled by having the DB creation done as part of the restore process.

Either way, thanks very much for your help, everybody!